# appending div with style not quite working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

i'm very fresh on the boat so please don't mind me if this is a dumb question, however, i was expecting the code below to append 11 divs into the #road container, with the top and left assigned via the variables.  the left position gets set as expected, but the top doesn't get set at all.  any help??

```
for (var a=0; a<11; a++) {
 left = getRandom(250,190)*a+250+a*20+'px';
 top = getRandom(220,0)+'px';
 $('#road').append('<div class=\"bumper\" style=\"left:'+left+';top:'+top+'\"></div>');
}

function getRandom(i,j) {
 var diff;
 var ranNum;
 diff = i-j;
 ranNum = i-Math.round(Math.random() * diff);
 return ranNum;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't get set how? The top setting doesn't take effect? There's no top value in the CSS you're generating? You don't get 11 divs?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon after `top:`:

```
$('#road').append('<div class=\"bumper\" style=\"left:'+left+'; top:'+top+';\"></div>');
```

Also, you don't need to escape double quotes in single quote strings, you'd only need to escape quotes inside strings if the string itself used that quote type.

```
$('#road').append('<div class="bumper" style="left:'+left+'; top:'+top+';"></div>');
```

**EDIT:**

From testing, it would appear that the with or without the last semicolon my browser (Chrome) doesn't complain. However, advice [here](http://www.boogiejack.com/CSS_3.html) says:

> You should always include the semi-colon after a rule, even if you're
>   only creating one rule. Truth is, a single rule will work most of the
>   time if you forget the semi-colon, but results can be unpredictable in
>   some instances. It's also a good habit. If you always include the
>   semi-colon for single rules, there's less of a chance you'll leave one
>   out where it's needed as a rules separator when you create multiple
>   rules for one selector.

It may or may not be a browser specific issue, if indeed it is the issue.

Comment: The semicolon is a *separator* in CSS, not a *terminator* so the last semicolon is optional.

Comment: The escaped quotes don't matter either, the escapes are redundant but harmless.

Comment: yes, it was just easier to read. Otherwise why not escape each character :P You're also correct, the ending semicolon is optional for inline CSS.

Comment: The ending semicolon is optional for all css, just look at a minified css file :)

Comment: you're right I corrected myself - it's only a separator. W3C were a bit ambiguous here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: W3C != w3schools, not even close. If you want useful information you should read the real specs at w3.org and you should check http://w3fools.com/ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code! The top value can able to set!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function appendDiv(){
    for (var a=0; a<11; a++) {
     left = getRandom(250,190)*a+250+a*20+'px';
     top = getRandom(220,0)+'px';
     $('#road').append('<div class="bumper" style="left:'+left+';top:'+top+'">asdfsd s</div>');
    }
}

function getRandom(i,j) {
 var diff;
 var ranNum;
 diff = i-j;
 ranNum = i-Math.round(Math.random() * diff);
 return ranNum;
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="appendDiv()" value="click">
<div id="road"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your script at the end of file

as iteration of `for` loop is not written in any function it gets called `before page load`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="road"></div>
</body>


<script>
for (var a=0; a<5; a++) {
  left = getRandom(250,190)*a+250+a*20+'px';
  top = getRandom(220,0)+'px';

 $('#road').append('<div class=\"bumper\" style=\"left:'+left+';top:'+top+'\">'+a+'</div>');
}

function getRandom(i,j) {
 var diff;
 var ranNum;
 diff = i-j;
 ranNum = i-Math.round(Math.random() * diff);
 return ranNum;
}
</script>
</html>
```